# "make install" errors

Tags: install-from-source

I am trying to install vmd on my ubuntu but " make install" is giving these errors. Can someone help? These are the errors. Thanks for the helps.

```
if [ ! -d "/usr/local/lib/vmd" ]; then \
        mkdir -p "/usr/local/lib/vmd" ; \
    fi ; \
    if [ ! -d "/usr/local/bin" ]; then \
        mkdir -p "/usr/local/bin" ; \
    fi ; \
    if [ ! -d "/usr/local/lib/vmd"/doc ]; then \
        mkdir -p "/usr/local/lib/vmd"/doc; \
    fi
cp ../Announcement  "/usr/local/lib/vmd"
cp: cannot create regular file `/usr/local/lib/vmd/Announcement': Permission denied
make: [install] Error 1 (ignored)
cp ../README        "/usr/local/lib/vmd"
cp: cannot create regular file `/usr/local/lib/vmd/README': Permission denied
make: [install] Error 1 (ignored)
cp ../LICENSE       "/usr/local/lib/vmd"
cp: cannot create regular file `/usr/local/lib/vmd/LICENSE': Permission denied
make: [install] Error 1 (ignored)
cp ../doc/ug.pdf        "/usr/local/lib/vmd"/doc
cp: cannot create regular file `/usr/local/lib/vmd/doc/ug.pdf': Permission denied
make: [install] Error 1 (ignored)
if [ -f /usr/local/lib/vmd/vmd_LINUXAMD64 ]; then \
           mv -f "/usr/local/lib/vmd/vmd_LINUXAMD64" "/usr/local/lib/vmd/OLD_vmd_LINUXAMD64" ; rm -f "/usr/local/lib/vmd/OLD_vmd_LINUXAMD64" ; fi
cp ../LINUXAMD64/vmd_LINUXAMD64 "/usr/local/lib/vmd"
cp: cannot overwrite directory `/usr/local/lib/vmd/vmd_LINUXAMD64' with non-directory
make: [install] Error 1 (ignored)
if [ -d "../lib/redistrib/lib_LINUXAMD64" ]; then \
        cd ../lib/redistrib/lib_LINUXAMD64; tar -cf - ./* | \
        (cd "/usr/local/lib/vmd" ; tar -xf -) \
    fi ;
tar: ./libcudart.so.4: Cannot open: Permission denied
tar: ./libexpat.so.0: Cannot open: Permission denied
tar: ./libsqlite3.so.0: Cannot open: Permission denied
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

> **sudo make install**

Generally make install needs root permissions to create new files in the filesystem.

Comment: <$>sudo make install</$> This Didnt Worked